# Is there a way to time each function like callgrind in python to measure source code execution time?

Tags: python, c, time, cpu, callgrind

I would like to measure the amount of time spent for each function in the c source codes but run in python with ctypes. Is there a way to use valgrind and callgrind with the python executions?